# How to get the order data before order placing

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, onepage-checkout, magento2.2

I created an events.xml at /app/code/Test/Customer/etc

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="checkout_submit_before">
      <observer name="Test_Customer_sales_order_place_before" instance="Test\Customer\Observer\OrderPlacebefore"/>
   </event>
</config>
```

Created the OrderPlacebefore.php like /app/code/Test/Customer/Observer

```
 <?php namespace Redington\CustomerAddress\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderPlacebefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {   
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->_request->getPost());
        exit;

       $quote = $observer->getQuote();

    }
}
```

I didn't get anything here. But I need to get all data of order like product details, totals and customer details.

Anyone, please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check blow code for get Order Data.

```
<?php namespace Redington\CustomerAddress\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderPlacebefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {   
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($observer->getOrder()->getData());
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: when placing this code, the page still loading from last 5mins.

Comment: Replace OrderPlacebefore class.

Comment: the same name I'm using the file name

Comment: Open OrderPlacebefore.php file and replace code with my answer code.

Comment: Yes I did that but same still loading

Comment: Use this event for it : sales_model_service_quote_submit_before

Comment: <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before"> but still loading the page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72858/discussion-between-suresh-chikani-and-venkata-prasad).